# Unexpected result of the mongodb query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two collection in the mongodb and by using $match and $sort I'm fetching the records in the database I also used `find().sort()` with the query but the result produce by the query is different. First I'm fetching the records from `section` collection using below query:-

**query 1**

```
db.section.find({"status":1}).sort({"display_order":1}).pretty()
```

Result produce by the above query is:-

```
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "name", "status" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "email", "status" : 1 }
```

and Using `$lookup` I'm fetching the record from both the collection combine with a forigen key the query is like given below:-

**query 2**

```
db.lead_section.aggregate([ 
  {$lookup: { "localField": "_id", 
              "from": "lead_field",   
              "foreignField": "lead_section_id", 
              "as": "custom_fields" }}, 
  {"$unwind": "$custom_fields"}, 
  {$match: {status: 1, "custom_fields.status": {$exists: true, $eq: 1}}}, 
  {"$sort": {"custom_fields.display_order": 1}}, 
  {"$group": { "_id":"$_id", "name":{"$first": "$name"}, 
               "status":{"$first": "$status"}, 
               "display_order": {"$first": "$display_order"},
               "custom_fields": {"$push": "$custom_fields"}}},
  {"$sort": {"display_order": 1}} ]).pretty()
```

This above query will produce the result like

```
 {
  "_id" : 2,
  "name" : "email",
  "status" : 1,
  "display_order" : null,
  "custom_fields" : [
    {
        "_id" : 2,
        "lead_section_id" : 2,
        "name" : "email2",
        "status" : 1
    }
  ]
}
{
  "_id" : 1,
  "name" : "name",
  "status" : 1,
  "display_order" : null,
  "custom_fields" : [
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "lead_section_id" : 1,
        "name" : "name2",
        "status" : 1
    }
  ]
}
```

I also change the query like below

```
 db.lead_section.aggregate([ 
  {$lookup: { "localField": "_id", 
              "from": "lead_field",   
              "foreignField": "lead_section_id", 
              "as": "custom_fields" }}, 
  {"$unwind": "$custom_fields"}, 
  {$match: {status: 1, "custom_fields.status": {$exists: true, $eq: 1}}}, 
  {"$sort": {"custom_fields.display_order": 1}}, 
  {"$group": { "_id":"$_id", "name":{"$first": "$name"}, 
               "status":{"$first": "$status"},
               "custom_fields": {"$push": "$custom_fields"}}},
  {"$sort": {"display_order": 1}} ]).pretty()
```

This query will remove the `display_order` field and rest result will same.

What is the difference between the `query 1` and `query 2` queries and how I will produce the same result of the both queries.

`($sort with display_order is necessary)`

anyone help me to solve this problem.
Thank you.

Comment: Why do you even sort the first query by a field `display_order` that does not exist in any of the documents? What should be the effect of this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that first you have to save the `display_order` field with `0` value then in query first you have to do `db.section.find({"status":1}).sort({"display_order":1,"_id":1}).pretty()`

This means if `display_order` value is exists then it will sort it with `display_order` either it will sort the data according to the `_id`

same sort in the query 2 like given below:-

```
 db.lead_section.aggregate([ 
    {$lookup: { "localField": "_id", 
                "from": "lead_field", 
                "foreignField": "lead_section_id", 
                "as": "custom_fields" }}, 
    {"$unwind": "$custom_fields"}, 
    {$match: {status: 1, "custom_fields.status": {$exists: true, $eq: 1}}}, 
    {"$sort": {"custom_fields.display_order": 1}}, 
    {"$group": { "_id":"$_id", 
                 "name":{"$first": "$name"}, 
                 "status":{"$first": "$status"}, 
                 "display_order": {"$first": "$display_order"}, 
                 "custom_fields": {"$push": "$custom_fields"}}}, 
    {"$sort": {"display_order": 1, "_id":1}} ]).pretty()
```

This will works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Here I have two collections **Users** and **User Profile**,
The below method will match the requested field also combine the two collections and throw the desired output:

```
const getUserData = async (userId) => {

            const getUserDataByUserId = await userDataModel.aggregate([
                {
                    $match: {
                        userId: userId
                    }
                }, {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: 'user_profiles',
                        localField: 'userId',
                        foreignField: 'userId',
                        as: 'users'
                    }
                }, {
                    $replaceRoot: {
                        newRoot: {
                            $mergeObjects: [{
                                $arrayElemAt: ["$users", 0]
                            }, "$$ROOT"]
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    $project: {
                        fromItems: 0
                    }
                }
            ]);

            return getUserDataByUserId;
        }
```